# Grab attribute of current record for Meteor Method Call

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working on a project to pull in twitter timeline's for selected teams/players.  When I am on the team/_id page, how can I grab an attribute to path through a method?

Below is my client side javascript, as well as the relevant route from iron router.  When I type in something like "patriots" to the "????" section, I get a result.  I would like to do this dynamically, I currently have the twitter handles stored under the twitter attribute.

```js
Template.tweets.helpers({
 teams: function() {
    return Teams.find();
  },
});

Template.tweets.onRendered(function () {
 var twitterHandle = "???";
    Meteor.call('getTimeline', twitterHandle, function(err,results){
     if (err) {
      console.log("error", error);
     };
     console.log(results);
     Session.set("twitter", JSON.parse(results.content));
    })
    return Session.get("twitter");
});


Router.route('/teams/:_id', {
    name: 'teamView',
    template: 'teamView',
    data: function(){
        var currentTeam = this.params._id;
        return Teams.findOne({ _id: currentTeam });
        var twitterHandle = this.params.twitter;
        return Teams.findOne({twitter: twitterHandle});
    }
});
```

```html
<template name="tweets">
 <h3>Tweets</h3>
 <div class="container">
  {{twitter}}
 </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access all information from the current route using the `Router.current()` object. In your case you can use `Router.current().params._id` to get the `_id` param:

```
var twitterHandle = Router.current().params._id;
```

**Edits based on your comments below**

I did not notice that you were calling the `Teams.findOne` function twice in your route's `data` function. Form the looks of it you're already storing the twitter handle in the `Teams` collection, so you merely need to access the `data` that's returned by the route.

```
Template.tweets.helpers({
    twitterData: function() {
        //return the data stored in the callback function of the Meteor method call in the onRendered event
        return Session.get('twitter');
    }
});

Template.tweets.onRendered(function () {
    //clear any previously stored data making the call
    Session.set('twitter', null);

    //property of the team document returned by the data function in the route.
    var twitterHandle = this.data.twitter;

    Meteor.call('getTimeline', twitterHandle, function(err,results){
        if (err) {
            console.log("error", error);
        } else {
            Session.set("twitter", JSON.parse(results.content));
        }
    });
});


Router.route('/teams/:_id', {
    name: 'teamView',
    template: 'teamView',
    data: function(){
        var currentTeam = this.params._id;
        return Teams.findOne({ _id: currentTeam });
    }
});

<template name="tweets">
    <h3>Tweets</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- twitterData will be an object, so you'll need to figure out what properties to display and use dot notation//-->
        {{twitterData}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Ok thank you.  If I want to get the "twitter" attribute of the current _id what would it be?  `var twitterHandle = Router.current().params.twitter; ` ? Was trying that before without any luck

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see that down in the code blow. I don't see the `twitter` param defined in the route? Are you passing it as a query string? If you want it to be available as a param you need to have it defined as part of the route string `/teams/:_id/:twitter`. Something like that.

Comment: If you are using a query string to pass in the twitter handle, you can use `Router.current().params.query.twitter` to get the value.

Comment: Did not try to create a new route (`/teams/:_id/:twitter`), but no luck with `Router.current().params.query.twitter`  :/  I'm a newb been wrestling with this guy for at least 12 hours

Comment: Can i define multiple data var's in the route? i have currentTeam already defined, and attempted to define twitterHandle

Comment: What does the URL for the page look like right now when you load it? Is it `/teams/patriots/somehandle` or is it `/teams/patriots?twitter=somehandle`?

Comment: just /teams/patriots ... i would like to embed the twitter feed in the page, so would there be another way to grab the attribute besides the url? thanks !

Comment: Added some suggestions. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Brian, your suggestions were very helpful.  Spent the last two days wrapping my head around subscriptions.  Seems that they used to only be managed via the routes, but now Meteor allows you to manage them on a template level with a subscription (and only call in the data you need). Thanks for all the help !!!