# Iron Router, Collection Helpers, and Session Variables. How to call an item attribute in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, collections, iron-router

I am working on a Meteor application and am trying to pass an attribute of an item in a collection to a javascript function.  In this instance I working with [instafeed.js](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js), a javascript plugin for the instagram API, but I would like to understand the process on a more fundamental level.

I’ve been able to pull records from my Teams collection into the `/teams/:id route`, and display attributes of a team using the `{{name}}` and `{{igHandle}}` template helpers.

I have also been able to get instafeed.js to work, using this package [etjana:instafeed](https://atmospherejs.com/etjana/instafeed) and the [demo](https://github.com/Ethaan/instafeed-meteor/tree/master/example) provided online.  The tag I am pulling is assigned statically via:`Session.setDefault(‘tagName’,’football’);`
Eventually I would like to pull the user profiles, but that requires an access token from oauth2.  I think that can be achieved with a `{{$.Session.get access_token}}` [handlebar helper](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers), but I need to figure out to feed a variable into the instafeed.js function first.

Could someone please explain how to pass the {{igHandle}} attribute through to the tagName in the javascript function.  My code is as follows:

**Team Template**:

```
<template name="teamView">
    <div class=“ui container”>
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
                <p>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://instagram.com/{{insta_hndl}}">&nbsp{{insta_hndl}}</a>
            </p>
            <br>
            <h3>Instagrams</h3>
            {{> igTeamFeed}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Everything works, except the {{>igTeamFeed}} render. I am able to get content to show, but it is currently static. *(assigned via `(Session.setDefault('tagValue','football')`.*

**Instafeed Template:**

```
<template name="igTeamFeed">
  <div class="ui container”>
    <h3>@{{insta_hndl}} Instagram</h3>
    <div id="instafeed"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Content is displaying, but again only through the static `(Session.setDefault('tagValue','football')` code.

**Router:**

```
Router.route('/teams/:_id', {
    name: 'teamView',
    template: 'teamView',
    data: function(){
        var currentTeam = this.params._id;
        return Teams.findOne({ _id: currentTeam });
    },
    action: function() {
        if (this.ready()) {
            this.render('teamView');
        } else {
            this.render('loading');
        }
    }
});
```

Works with template helpers, so I am thinking I am ok here.  Also following the instructions of a user per one of my [prior posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931330/grab-attribute-of-current-record-for-meteor-method-call/31931418#31931418).

**Instafeed Javascipt:** (needs some work)

```
Template.igTeamFeed.helpers ({
  igData: function() {
    return Session.get('insta_hndl');
  },
});

Template.igTeamFeed.onRendered(function () {
    //clear any previously stored data making the call
    Session.get('insta_hndl'); //extra add-in
    Session.set('insta_hndl', null);
    Session.set('insta_hndl', this.data.insta_hndl); //extra add-in

    var igHandle = this.data.insta_hndl;

});

Tracker.autorun(function(){
    feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: Session.get('insta_hndl'),
        clientId: ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’,
        resolution: 'thumbnail',
        sortBy: 'most-liked',
        limit: '15'
    });

    feed.run();
});
```

- I have a helper to get the current `insta_hndl` for the session.  The session item is passed through the `team/:_id` tag of the url, and defined in the router
- The `onRendered` is wiping out the old handle, and inserting the new one.  I added two additional `Session.get` and `Session.set` functions since I was getting an error that `insta_hndl` was undefined (differing from the response on my previous post).  Could be wrong there.
- The `tracker.autorun` function was code I had working with an instafeed example.  Should it be somewhere else? Maybe in a `helper` or `onRendered` function?  Also do I need `tracker.autorun` to use instafeed? To my understanding it dynamically updates the feed when a `tagName` changes, but aren't there other ways to do this?

**How to Solve**
These are some ways I'm thinking I could to solve this.  Please advise on how to do this / what you think is best practice:

- [Collection Helpers](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers): Was thinking I could call something like `Teams.findOne().insta_hndl` but didn't have much luck.  Is that the right code block to use? Do I have to define a variable in the template helper, or can I call it directly in the feed js function?
- [Handlebars Helpers](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers): Thinking I could do something with a Session helper, but not sure if it would work if one user had two different instances of the instafeed open (two tabs open with different teams selected).
- [Reactive Methods](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method): Allows one to call methods synchronously inside Tracker.autorun.  Thought i read something that said Meteor already has this functionality baked in, but please advise.
- [Iron Router Query](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router#query-parameters): Part of me still isn't convinced the insta_hndl isn't getting passed through.  I've explored adding the instagram handle as a query param to the URL, but do not think this is a best practice.

If someone could help me get this working that woudld be great, but explanations would even better! Really spending a lot of time on this, and many of the online resources are using depreciated syntax.

Also two more related questions questions:

Should I use a controller? Should i write out a controller separately? Or just include it in `Router.route` functions?  Seeing some people rely heavily on controllers, but a lot of documentation does everything through `Router.route`.

Should I break out the instafeed function into a `method`? If so how should I do this?  I spent a great amount of time tryig to set up the whole instafeed function as a server side method, but couldn't seem to get it to work.  I only foresee myself using this function in one or two other templates, so I figured it was fine to leave as is.  Please advice.

Comment: I'm so confused after reading this! Could you break down a bit part and bits and focus in the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that this was a bit confusing.  The correct javascript is:

```
Template.igTeamFeed.helpers ({
    teams: function() {
    return Teams.find();
  }
});

Template.igTeamFeed.onCreated( function() {

    var igHandle = Teams.findOne(Router.current().params._id).insta_hndl;

    feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: Session.get('insta_hndl'),
        clientId: ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’,
        resolution: 'thumbnail',
        sortBy: 'most-liked',
        limit: '15'
    });

    feed.run(); //run the new Instafeed({})
});
```

There is no need for any of the things I suggested.  The attribute can be grabbed with Collection.findOne(Router.current().params._id).attrib, where Collection is your collection and attrib is the non-_id value you want to grab.

Also did not need tracker.autorun, that was throwing me off as well.